# Web socket error close codes specific to browser

Tags: websocket, jetty

I am using Websockets in my application for streaming purpose .
I am using Jetty in back end for this purpose

On to the onclose call back method i have this

```
@Override
    public void onClose(int arg0, String arg1) {
        logger.info("In onClose :: " + arg0 + " :: " + arg1);
}
```

What i observed is that , the error codes are not generic but specific to browser that is

When i use chrome it displays `1006` , if browser is closed using ctrl+w , Clicked on Cross Button , or even  user clicked on logout button

but where as in firefox it displays `1001` if browser is closed using ctrl+w , Clicked on Cross Button , or even  user clicked on logout button

Now the problem is that i really cannot identify why a disconnect has been happened , because as it being a browser specific  ??

please share your views as how to debug in such cases ??

Answer (score 2):

This may help:

https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6455#section-7.4.1

Specifically:

> 1001 indicates that an endpoint is "going away", such as a server
> going down or a browser having navigated away from a page.>

and

> 1006 is a reserved value and MUST NOT be set as a status code in a
> Close control frame by an endpoint.  It is designated for use in
> applications expecting a status code to indicate that the connection
> was closed abnormally, e.g., without sending or receiving a Close
> control frame.

So I am going to guess that you're looking at this from the server standpoint in which case the 1006 would indicate that the chrome endpoint did not behave well and the server reacted to that with the special close code.  In your client side I would start debugging it to ensure it makes it into whatever close code is required to get that actual close code of 1001 back to the server.  Now you may not be able to get to close logic in all of your scenarios, that is why this close code exists in the first place, but you should at least be able to close the connection cleanly via your own logout button.

Comment: Shouldn't i be getting code as 1000 and not 1001  on any browser when user clicks on logout button , please correct me in case i was wrong .

Comment: Would depend what is going on with that logout button, some javascript framework is working on your behalf there I suspect.  If you are not getting 1000 at _all_ then I would say something in hinky client side.

Comment: close code 1000 is for your code to issue.  no javascript framework should be issuing a close 1000 automatically for you.   for firefox to send 1001 is a sane response to a harsh tab/browser close.  for chrome to not send a close but instead rely on the server side EOF detection and subsequent abnormal (not clean) close code 1006 is also a sane reaction to your use case.